# M1 MacBook Pro jumps text while typing

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad, multi-touch

On the M1 MacBook Pro, when I am typing it will frequently jump to another part of the text area. This is most pronounced when selecting text using the keyboard (shift-left..., shift-option-left...) and results in letters going where they are not supposed to.

Operating systems have "accidental click protection" to prevent touchpad taps from counting while typing. But this M1 suffers from a lot more accidental taps registering.

*I have used maybe every portable Apple has made since the black-and-white PowerBooks. This is the first time I've seen this problem to this degree.*

Is this a common/known issue with M1 portables?

Answer (score 0):

This happened on my M1 MBP, and is now happening on my M2. It is really annoying. I see it mostly when I'm typing fairly fast. The jump is sometimes to the Home of the current page, and sometimes to some location a few lines above where I am typing. The exact location appears to be application dependent. My interpretation of it is that due to inadequate debouncing of the keyboard keys, sometimes a spurious control character is received, cause the jump. The other, equally annoying “jump” that it does is to switch to another Input Source. I have several of those enabled on my system for language-learning purposes, and so I might discover that I'm typing a few Cyrillic or Hiragana characters in the middle of the English text.

Update 1: I believe that I have figured out a solution in my case. I changed the trackpad click force setting from “Light" to "Medium". I think that as I typed, my hand was making light contact with the trackpad which sometimes registered as a click, in combination with whatever key(s) I was typing, causing the jumps. By increasing the force needed to register as a click, I think I've eliminated the spurious clicks and therefore the problem. It certainly seems to be behaving better now.

Update 2: OK, changing the trackpad click force setting isn't a complete fix, the problem can still occur, but much less often than when the setting is "Light". At least this suggests that the underlying problem is spurious trackpad clicks or other activity.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/342807)

Answer (score 0):

Based on supporting hundreds of people using this hardware, it's not common, however that's of little use to anyone that has problems with their hardware. Two people did have issues, but once we got a video chat with them to see their setups - one had jewelry what was making contact with the case and the other was hovering their forearm / palm on the trackpad (and you don't have to actually touch the sensor for it to start to track). Both were able to change their habits and none were due to hardware, but I could see an overly sensitive / broken hardware cause this in theory.

I would get a backup - make sure you are able to restore from the backup and then reset the Mac and test with no personal apps / data / customization to be 100% sure it's due to a plain macOS install and your hardware before reaching out to Apple support for support.